# How to create a rounded area (Circle) in Android? Can find only Rect for rectangles

Tags: android, geometry, intersection, area, rect

I need to check if two ImageViews with rounded images are intersecting. The problem is that I can find only Rect in the documentation for define areas and do Intersect, and Rect is for rectangles.

Is not possible in Android to define rounded areas and check if two are intersecting?

This is the code for Rect:

```
Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2)
```

Comment: If you are truly talking about circles and not ovals, then no area computation needed. Calculate the distance between the two centers, and if less than radius1 + radius2, they are intersecting.

Comment: @dharms thank you, but what if they are ovals for example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is hard to recommend an approach without more details.